# hosting Wcf service via ServerHost in IIS，Console or winform App can add reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

Hosting in IIS，web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true">
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AllenBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1000"  maxConcurrentSessions="1000" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="jqueryWCF.WCFservice" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://127.0.0.1:9999/Service"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="AllenBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="jqueryWCF.WCFservice" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"
 contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>

    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

1 web page  access success by JQuery ajax
2 Metadata is also released, the URL access success;

****But why the console app add service reference will appear "object reference not set to an instance of an object***"????*

Comment: Issue seems to be in the console app. Better post the code where the error occurs instead

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something wrong with metadata of your WCF service. 
Check operations contracts definition. 
Do not you have conflicting contract names?

Try to use [ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool (Svcutil.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) to generated client code from WSDL instead of Visual Studio tool